# Method of Characteristics - Can we have multiple answers

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Determine the characteristics of the equation $z=p^2-q^2$, and find the integral surface which passes through the parabola $4z+x^2=0$, $y=0$.

I solved the question and my answer was:
The characteristics are
$x=2\lambda-\lambda e^{-t}$
$y=\sqrt{2}\lambda-\sqrt{2}\lambda e^{-t}$
$z=\frac{-\lambda^2}{4}e^{-2t}$
The Integral surface is $4z+(\sqrt{2}y-x)^2=0$

The answer in the textbook was:
The characteristics are
$x=2\lambda(2-e^{-t})$
$y=2\sqrt{2}\lambda(e^{-t}-1)$
$z={-\lambda^2}e^{-2t}$
The Integral surface is $4z+(\sqrt{2}y+x)^2=0$

$\lambda$ is a parameter. Hence the change in multiple of 2. However the integral surface was supposed to be the same.

I found the difference was due to the way i took $q_0$. 
After taking $x_0 = \lambda$, 
$y_0=0$, $z_0=-\frac{\lambda^2}{4}$

Solving for $p_0$ and $q_0$ accordingly,

$p_0=\frac{-\lambda}{2}$

$q_0^2=\frac{\lambda^2}{2}$

here when i take positive root of $q_0$, i get my solution. But when i take negative root, i get the one in textbook.
Are both solutions correct?. If not, why? My textbook does not show both solutions

Thanks in Advance

Comment: They are the same surfaces, just parameterized differently (your $\lambda$ is half of the $\lambda$ in the book). So the answers are the same. There are infinitely many ways to parametrize any surface, so the book cannot include all.